# How to find the font-name,size,style, text color from rich text-box text in c#

Tags: c#, .net, richtextbox

In my application I have a rich text-box.I use that as a text editor. I can change font,size, style when I needed. now my problem is I want to find out font-name,size, text-color of each character ?
i,e i want to retrieve every character's font-name,size, text-color after editing is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [SelectionFont](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionfont%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property to retrieve the font of the currently selected text. Similarly, you can use the [SelectionColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectioncolor%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) property.

Answer (score 2):

Never done this personally and no time to test at the moment, but the: [Groups RV's DotNET forum](http://www.groupsrv.com/dotnet/about32907.html) may have your solution. Perhaps something like mentioned in the post:

```
for (int iCurChar = lastChar; iCurChar
richTextBox1.Text.Length; iCurChar++)
{
richTextBox1.Select(iCurChar,1);
char CurrChar = richTextBox1.Text[iCurChar];
Color CurrColor = richTextBox1.SelectionColor;
Font CurrFont = richTextBox1.SelectionFont;
float fontSize = CurrFont.Size 
}
```

Taking a look at the Font class may be useful as well: [Microsoft's Font Reference Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.aspx)